# Appending static html attribute to Knockout.js data-bind

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm binding json from a file and it works fine. the binding is being done on a html table:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ordertracking_template">
    <tr>  
      <td data-bind="text:ClientName"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: SalesCohorts -->
      <td data-bind="text: TotalCohortSales">/td>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <td data-bind="text: TotalSalesInTargetPeriod"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Now, my desire is to add a link in the same row as the **TotalCohortSales**. i.e.

```
<!-- ko foreach: SalesCohorts -->
<td data-bind="text: TotalCohortSales"><pre><a href="">Orders</a></pre>/td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

like shown above but thats not happening. the data is being binded but the added `<pre><a href="">Orders</a></pre>` elements are not rendered.

I hope the information i've provided above is enough for someone to be able to chip in with some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
  <!-- ko foreach: SalesCohorts -->
  <td data-bind="text: TotalCohortSales">/td>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

you are defining the content (innerHTML) of this row (`<td>`).  You can't add nothing else to this row.

If you want to write more data, you need to separe the `<td>` from its content:

```
  <!-- ko foreach: SalesCohorts -->
  <td>
     <span data-bind="text: TotalCohortSales"></span>
     <pre><a href="">Orders</a></pre>
  </td>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

Now you'll have one column per each `SalesCohorts`.  And inside this column you'll get the `TotalCohortSales` and the link.

Comment: Excellent explanation